# Как выделять не все li, а только тот, который в hover?

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, анимация, hover

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне выделять не все пункты li (.card), а только тот, который в hover должен быть?

Верстка упрощена для вопроса.

В целом - при наведении на карточку должны срабатывать несколько действий: Анимация, изменение цвета... у нескольких других, встроенных в li элементов.

И я не разобрался как это сделать с $(this)

```
<ul class="works-list">
    <li class="card"><h4>One</h4><p>School</p><div></div></li>
    <li class="card"><h4>Two</h4><p>Home</p><div></div></li>
    <li class="card"><h4>Three</h4><p>Neighbor</p><div></div></li>
</ul>

$(".card").hover(
    function() {
        $(".card h4").toggleClass("work-active anime-white");
        $(".card p").toggleClass("work-active-sub anime-white");
        $(".card .blue-line").toggleClass(" blue-line-hover");
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
 $(".works-list .card").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('.h4').toggleClass("work-active anime-green");
         $(this).find('.p').toggleClass("work-active anime-red");
    });
```

```css
.anime-red {color:red;}
.anime-green {color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="works-list">
    <li class="card"><h4 class="h4">One</h4><p class="p">School</p><div></div></li>
    <li class="card"><h4 class="h4">Two</h4><p class="p">Home</p><div></div></li>
    <li class="card"><h4 class="h4">Three</h4><p class="p">Neighbor</p><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, 
$(this) применяется тут к самому li, как и стили анимации, а мне нужно что бы они срабатывали к (".card h4"), (".card p"), (".card .blue-line")
То есть, - к другим элементам, но при наведении на каждый из списка пункт li

Comment: переделал насколько понял

Comment: Да, чувак, спасибо большое.
Через .(find) теперь буду знать что можно так... В строку делать.

ps
h4 и p - классом)))